# How do I patch a route in spring cloud gateway via environment variables

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have a static route configuration on Spring cloud gateway, is there a way of patching part of it using environment variables?

e.g. SPRING_CLOUD_GATEWAY_ROUTES_20_URI: https://httpbin.org/base64/W10%3D